# Can't resolve all parameters for DecimalPipe - ngBootstrap/Angular2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm new to angular2 and i try to learn by doing. But here I am, completely stuck!

I tried to import ng-boostrap and I have this issue : [image]

Here is my systemjs.config.js : 
[image]

And here is my package.json: 
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve and understand this issue ? 
Thank you :).

Comment: Where and how are you using the `DecimalPipe`?

Comment: You are mixing different version of `@angular` packages and also including 2 different routers.... This can't end up well :-) Clean-up your package.json first.

Comment: @Dave : This is the thing ... I'm not using it my-self :/. That's why i can't understand this error.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource : Yeah I have to do that. I used the starter kit from angular2 so... Thanks guys :) !

Answer (score 1):

The DecimalPipe is exported from @angular/common.  The version of DecimalPipe that you are using (version 2.0.0 as shown in your package.json) requires LOCALE_ID to be injected.  LOCALE_ID is exported from @angular/core.  Since you are using @angular/core version 2.0.0-rc.5 it doesn't include LOCALE_ID.  When angular tries to inject LOCALE_ID into DecimalPipe, it fails since LOCALE_ID doesn't exist in rc5.

Update your version for @angular/core.  All the @angular things (except router) should be at the same version.  You should either change them all to rc.5 to match your core module, or even better update all of them to 2.0.1.

@angular/router is currently at 3.0.0-rc.2. You are installing both the current router and the deprecated router.  Although that is not causing your current error, it will potentially cause many other errors.  I would suggest removing the deprecated router and updating the actual router to 3.0.0-rc.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot @arthurzp ! I will try your solution this evening and i'll come back to share if it works :).